# Expressing if else statements more succintly when null variable is posted from form

Tags: php

Is there a better way to express this PHP code? I've received variables from a form and now need to check whether they are null or not before outputting a text string.

Many thanks in advance!

```
$Capacity = $_POST["Capacity"];
$Location = $_POST["Location"];
$RoomType = $_POST["RoomType"];

echo '<div id="container" style="padding: 15px; background-color: #949494;">';
echo '<div style="padding: 15px; background-color: #fff;">';
echo '<h2>Search results:</h2>';
echo '<h3>Showing';
if ($RoomType == '') echo ''; else echo ' '.$RoomType.' ';
echo ' rooms with a capacity of '. $Capacity .' and over';
if ($Location == '') echo ''; else echo ' in  '.$Location.' Park';
echo '</h3>';
```

Comment: Tangential point: Directly echoing user-input data is potentially opening yourself up to an XSS attack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2:** I revisited the code, so that it makes more sense.

```
<?php
$requiredFields = array(
    'Capacity',
    'Location',
    'RoomType'
);
// Retrieve only the allowed fields
$fields = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($requiredFields));
// Remove whitespace
$fields = array_map('trim', $fields);
// Remove empty values
$fields = array_filter($fields, 'strlen');
// Filter values for HTML output
$fields = array_map('htmlentities', $fields);

// We require all fields
if(count($fields) !== count($requiredFields)) {
    exit('Your browser sent incorrect data!');
}

// Create the variables
extract($fields, EXTR_SKIP);
?>
<h2>Search Results</h2>
<h3><?php printf('Showing %s rooms with a capacity of %s and over in %s Park', $RoomType, $Capacity, $Location) ?></h3>
```

**Edit:** Added `htmlentities` filter

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Lazy input validation

Comment: the opening poster didn't ask for such input validation

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I interpret "Is there a better way to express this PHP code?" as a call for general code improvement

Comment: Check the title. it is more certain

Comment: @Vague I would like to use your code but don't need the input validation. How would I adjust the code to remove it?

Comment: @methuselah remove the code below `// Remove empty values` and `// We require all fields`

Answer (score 0):

```php
/* Safely retrieve input parameters */
$Capacity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Capacity', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$Location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Location', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$RoomType = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'RoomType', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
/* Define html template */
$tmpl = <<<EOFHTML
<div id="container" style="padding: 15px; background-color: #949494;">
<div style="padding: 15px; background-color: #fff;">
<h2>Search results:</h2>
<h3>Showing %s rooms with a capacity of %s and over %s
</h3>
EOFHTML;
/* Output result */
if( !empty($Location)) $Location = ' in '.$Location.' Park ';
printf( $tmpl, $RoomType, $Capacity, $Location);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the "ternary operator"  It is called ternary because it takes three operands (unlike say "plus" which is a binary operator taking two operands).  Operands aside, it works like this

```
some true/false expression   ?   result when true  :  result when false
```

from your example:

```
echo ($RoomType == '') ? '' : ' '.$RoomType.' ';
```

Comment: Would this potentially open me up to an XSS attack?

Comment: No more or less than the original.  I was addressing only the question of "expressing if/else statements more succinctly".

Answer (score -1):

I see no point in such checking

```
$Capacity = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Capacity"]);
$Location = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Location"]);
$RoomType = htmlspecialchars($_POST["RoomType"]);

echo "<div id='container' style='padding: 15px; background-color: #949494;'>
<div style='padding: 15px; background-color: #fff;'>
<h2>Search results:</h2>
<h3>Showing $RoomType rooms with a capacity of $Capacity and over in  $Location Park</h3>";
```

is okay.

Comment: If $Location is empty you got an strange phrase '..and over in Park'